# Get same url structure as on Stack Overflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

A question on SO has this url structure:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474799/changing-the-input-value-in-html5-datalist`

If we assume that the number section is the ID, the first two sections (after the domain extension) are obtained by simply using the following in routes.rb

`resources :questions`

The question is already identified by it's ID, so how do we add the (optional) decorating slug in the simplest of manners? Do we need to use a new link helper (and including additional params) or can the 3-section url be resolved elsewhere?

**Update:**

To focus this question more on the route-handling, let's presume there is already a slug saved on the object (upon creation) as an attribute, e.g. `@question.slug`

It would really be an advantage if a rule in `routes.rb` or/and in the controller could enable and handle the optional slug, instead of having to write long link helpers in all views.

Answer (score 1):

```
resources :questions do
  member: title
end
```

for slug use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) and yes don't forget to have a look at [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to handle the GET requests in that manner, it's easy to do:

```
get '/questions/:id/:title' => 'questions#show',  as: :question_with_title
resources :questions
```

This way you can handle incoming URLs with or without the title (just as StackOverflow can -- try it!).  You can create urls dynamically with something like:

```
question_with_title_path(@question.id, @question.title.to_s.downcase.gsub(/ /, '-')
# probably will want to use a method for processing titles into url-friendly format
```

More at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#static-segments

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the `to_param` method to create a "friendly id".

Something like this:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    [id, name.parameterize].join("/")
  end
end
```

More info in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/cdmwebs/1209732)