# HTML5 datalists - displaying list of options programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, datalist, html-datalist

I'm new to HTML5 datalists. I have setup an `<input type="text">` tied to a `<datalist>` following:

- [HTML datalist Tag - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp)
- [HTML5 Datalist: What You Need To Know - The JotForm Blog](https://www.jotform.com/blog/html5-datalists-what-you-need-to-know-78024/)

For instance:

```html
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Chrome / Chromium shows the input as a combobox, allowing one to list all the possible values:

[image: Datalist on Chrome / Chromium]

Firefox displays the input as any other text field, but I realized one can display all the options double clicking the field, or clicking the field and pressing the down arrow key:

[image: Datalist on Firefox]

I need to implement a browser-agnostic button that shows that list of options when it is clicked. Like:

```html
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
<button type="button">Show options</button>
```

[image: Show options button]

How can I implement such a button?

Comment: Wow, a thorough internet search has given me no answers. I've tried everything I know in javascript to simulate clicks or autofocus on the datalist... nothing works. My best advice is to simply use a `placeholder` attribute, or maybe a framework like Bootstrap to add a fancy label to your list that lets people know what's up.

Comment: That's why I asked on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: And StackOverflow is stumped too, looks like.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133661/programmatically-make-datalist-of-inputtype-url-appear-with-javascript  ... If simply using a placeholder or label is not a viable solution, you'll have to build your own custom selector using jQuery or something.

Comment: What I already tried: simulating pressing the down arrow key, but it did not work. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455626/keydown-simulation-in-chrome-fires-normally-but-not-the-correct-key/12522769#comment68243143_10455626